# How React to get cache data from backend and reuse it in another component?

Tags: python, reactjs, sqlite, flask, react-query

I have a table in database called Notes that have userid link with user table, so when user login, backend gets username that match with userid, and when create notes will need to retrieve userid so that the note data will save in database that links with that user. I try to use react query and mutation to get the cache.

This is login.js:

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';
import axios from '../api/axios';
import { Link, useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useLoginMutation } from '../hooks/useLoginMutation';

const LOGIN_URL = '/auth'; //connect backend



const Login = () => {
    //to access the value of a context object that has been created using the createContext function
    const { setAuth } = useAuth();
    
    const { mutate } = useLoginMutation();

    const navi= useNavigate();
    const location =useLocation();
    const from= location.state?.from?.pathname || "/home"; 
   
    //focus area
    const userRef = useRef();
    const errRef = useRef();

    const [user, setUser] = useState('');
    const [pwd, setPwd] = useState('');
    const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState('');


    useEffect(() => {
        userRef.current.focus();
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        setErrMsg('');
    }, [user, pwd])


    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            //define response ()
            const response = await axios.post(LOGIN_URL,
                //api
                JSON.stringify({ user, pwd }),
                {
                    //third object
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    withCredentials: true
                }
            );
          
            //only data property
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response?.data));
            //all data
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            const user = response.data.username;
            const accessToken = response?.data?.accessToken; 
            //array
            const roles = response?.data?.roles;
            

            setAuth({ user, pwd, roles, accessToken });
            setUser('');
            setPwd('');
            // Call the mutation hook to perform login and set username in cache
            await mutate({ user, pwd }); //to store the username in the cache 
            navi(from, {replace:true});
             
        } catch (err) {
            if (!err?.response) {
                setErrMsg('No Server Response');
            } else if (err.response?.status === 400) {
                //expected info not exist
                setErrMsg('Missing Username or Password');
            } else if (err.response?.status === 401) {
                setErrMsg('Unauthorized');
            } else {
                setErrMsg('Login Failed');
            }
            errRef.current.focus(); //screen reader focus error display
        }
    }
```

This is useLoginMutation.js:

```
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from 'react-query';
import axios from 'axios'; 

export const useLoginMutation = () => {
    const LOGIN_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/auth'; 
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();


    return useMutation(
        async ({ user, pwd }) => {
            const response = await axios.post(LOGIN_URL, JSON.stringify({ user, pwd }), {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                withCredentials: true,
            });
            return response.data;
        },
        {
            //executed when the login request is successful. 
            onSuccess: (data) => {
                //queryClient is used to update the cached username data. The key 'username' is used to identify this specific query in the cache, and the username data is set to data.user which comes from the response.
                queryClient.setQueryData('username', data.user);
                console.log(data.user);
            },
        }
    );
};
```

This is createNote.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {useState} from 'react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

import { useLoginMutation } from '../hooks/useLoginMutation';



const CreateNote = ({handleAddNote}) =>{

   
    const fetchEmail= async()=>{

        const response = await axios.post(
            'http://localhost:5000/auth', // URL for the POST request
            JSON.stringify({ user:'' }), // Request body data
            {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                withCredentials: true,
            }
        );
        return response.data.user;
        
    }
    

    
    const CREATENOTE_URL= 'http://localhost:5000/Create_Notes';
     // Fetch username from the cache using useQuery
     //const { data: usernameData } = useQuery('username',() => {});

    const [noteText, setNoteText]= useState('');
   

    const {data: emailData} =useQuery('email',fetchEmail);
    const loginMutation = useLoginMutation();

    

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setNoteText(event.target.value);
        console.log(event.target.value);
    };

    //event is text input
    const handleSaveClick = async () => {
        if (noteText.trim().length > 0) {
            // Perform login mutation to fetch username
            await loginMutation.mutateAsync({ user: '', pwd: '' });

            //access the username from the cache using the 'email' query
            const username = emailData;
            console.log('Username from cache:', username);

            // Handle adding the note here
            handleAddNote(noteText);
            setNoteText('');
        }
    };
```

This is index.js:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <AuthProvider>
        <UserContextProvider>
          <Routes>
            
            <Route path="/*" element={<App />} />
          </Routes>
        </UserContextProvider>
      </AuthProvider>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
  </QueryClientProvider>
);
```

This is backend:

```
def create_table():
    with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                username TEXT NOT NULL,
                password TEXT NOT NULL
            )
             ''')
        cursor.execute(''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notes(
                notesid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                notes   TEXT, 
                notestist INTEGER, username TEXT NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(notestist) REFERENCES users(id)
            )
         ''')
        conn.commit()
create_table()

# Endpoint for user authentication (login)
@app.route('/auth', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    data = request.get_json()
    username = data.get('user')
    password = data.get('pwd')
    if not username or not password:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Missing Username or Password'}), 400

    with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Check if the username and password match a user in the database
        cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?", (username, password))
        authenticated_user = cursor.fetchone()
        if not authenticated_user:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Unauthorized'}), 401
        
        cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?", (username,))
    user_data = cursor.fetchone()
    if user_data:
        user_username = user_data[0]
        return jsonify({'message': 'Login Successful', 'username': user_username}), 200
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Username not found'}), 404


@app.route('/Create_Notes', methods=['POST'])
def Create_Notes():
    data = request.get_json()
    username = data.get('email')
    notes = data.get('notes')
    if not username:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Users Does Not Exist'}), 400

    with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        # update_query = "INSERT INTO notes (notes, username) VALUES (?, ?)"
        update_query = "INSERT INTO notes (notes, username) VALUES ( ?, (SELECT id from users  WHERE username=?));"
        cursor.execute(update_query, (notes, username))
        conn.commit()

    return jsonify({'message': 'Notes Saved Successfully'}), 201
```

when I createnote and click save button, console come with this error:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received

xhr.js:244     POST http://localhost:5000/auth 400 (BAD REQUEST)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6gCd.png)

the purpose is I want to save the notes in database created by user , the first things is I need to get username which is the email when user login, and reuse the email, then pass the email, and noteText to backend and save in database, but it doesn't work, I ask for chatgpt all solution cannot solve..